# Creating my own Qt widget for a search box

Tags: qt4, desktop-application

my question is somewhat related to [Search button inside the search box like Bing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581824/search-button-inside-the-search-box-like-bing). I plan to use a similar control to provide search facility within my desktop application. The search box is somewhat like the search box given in the windows explorer in Windows 7 where the text "search" appears and when the user enters text to search it'll show suggestions and close matches. Also when the search query is cleared there'll be a slight transition such as a fade out, so that the entire control looks smooth in operation.

I haven't done this using MFC/Windows programming, but I've a feeling this should be easier on Qt. I've seen the Qt example using QML but i don't plan to use QML.

Can you guys suggest a way for me to do this in Qt ?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`QLineEdit`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html) with a [`QCompleter`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html) , for the Windows 7 search box effect see [`setPlaceHolderText(...)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#placeholderText-prop) function.

Comment: sadly that does not offer the ability to give a slight transition as the one show in the Search Box demo using QML.

Comment: If its possible in QML its possible with C++ too :)

Comment: Yes Im thinking of doing a custom draw, using QStyle classes to capture control events and draw the control as I want it. But I am not sure how much of trouble Id run into. THis is simply the reason I needed help from the community.