# Search button inside the search box

Tags: html, css

I want to  implement a search button inside the search box, and i find it useful:[Search button inside the search box like Bing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581824/search-button-inside-the-search-box-like-bing)

but when i place code into my site, it didn't show the way expected,what's wrong?

this is the code

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="q" />
<input type="button" id="b" value="Search" />
```

**CSS**

```
#q, #b { 
   margin: 0 
}
#q { 
   padding 5px; 
   font-size: 2em; 
   line-height: 30px 
}
#b { 
   /* image replacement */
   text-indent: -99999px; 
   width: 30px; 
   height: 30px; 
   display: block;
   background: gray url(button.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

[code](http://jsfiddle.net/SjafT/502/)

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
#q, #b { 
   margin: 0 
   display:inline-block;
   float:left;
}
#q { 
   padding 5px; 
   font-size: 2em; 
   line-height: 30px; 
   border:none;
}
#b { 
   /* image replacement */
    margin-top:8px;
   width: 30px; 
   height: 30px; 
   background: gray url(button.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
.border {
   border:#ccc solid 1px; 
   width:390px;
}
.clear {
   clear:both;
}

<div class="border">
<input type="text" id="q" />
<input type="button" id="b" value="Search" />
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

[Check this out](http://jsfiddle.net/exvEC/)

Answer (score 1):

look at this:[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SjafT/513/)

html:

```
<div>
<input type="text" id="q" />
<input type="button" id="b" value="Search" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#q, #b { 
   margin: 0 
}
#q { 
   padding 5px; 
   font-size: 2em; 
   padding-left:50px;
   line-height: 30px 
}
#b { 
   /* image replacement */
   text-indent: -99999px; 
   width: 30px; 
   height: 30px; 
   display: block;
    position:absolute;
    top:4px;
    left:4px;
   background: gray url(button.png) 0 0 no-repeat;

   /* placing next to input using float or absolute positioning omitted ... */
}
div{
    position:relative;
}
```